# ranger clutch problems

Tags: ford, clutch

I just tried starting my 99 ranger I just acquired . The truck hasn't been started for over a year, it was parked because the owner believed it had a lower end bearing knock. I started the truck and this is the issue,clutch peddle stuck to floor  truck makes a tinny knock when started??

Comment: has anyone ever had a throw-out-bearing fork break?

Comment: is the pedal cable or fluid? Has the clutch plate stuck to the flywheel face?